# What happens if two tasks - for writing data to a file - are executed at the same time in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server that mainly receives data, opens a `JSON` file, does some processing based on the received data, and then writes the new `JSON` data to the file.

If two tasks are executed at the same time, will this ignore or destroy the other task`s job (will one of them be ignored or something)? I'm a little bit confused about that.

Comment: You can implement a lock mechanism to avoid 2nd task doing the same task in parallel.

Comment: This is a classic problem of concurrent resource access. While you can try solving it using locks, you might also realize that maybe using JSON for storage is not the ideal solution here. If you use some database package to store you data, they would usually take care of locking an unlocking. I use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html), which is a very lightweight database, and it supports concurrency.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.